# Play 1.3.4 to spring boot 2.0 migration

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, playframework, playframework-1.x

I want to migrate my Play framework-1.3.4 to Spring boot-2.0 as per my client requirement. I am new to spring/spring boot.

I googled lot but didn't find any article for step by step migration.

Can anyone answer me for following question:

- How to start a migration
- A step by step guide would be appreciable.
- If anyone faced any challenges.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `spring-boot` and `play framework` are totally different.
you need to start a `spring-boot` project from scratch.

Comment: I need some input on what is the alternative of  templates, How we use the JPA with Spring boot, etc. to starting with Spring boot. If you have any link/material please share it, otherwise I will google it.Thanks in advance! @GovindSingh